# Deleting authentication credentials in objective c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I'm making HTTP requests with urls like "http://user:password@example.com/stuff.xml" and I'm noticing that the user credentials are getting cached and used. If I attempt to log in first with invalid credentials, it doesn't work. But if I log in with a valid username/password, then try to login in again with an invalid username/password, it uses the valid credentials I just used rather than what is in the url.

I've been looking at [NSURLCredentialStorage](http://NSURLCredentialStorage) to possibly delete whatever is saved, but I need to specify a [NSURLProtectionSpace](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLProtectionSpace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSURLProtectionSpace) and I'm not sure what that is.

**Update**:

I made a `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge` delegate method that sets the username and password in a `NSURLCredential` with the persistence set to   `NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone`, but it seems that delegate method doesn't even get called the 2nd time around.

**Update 2**:

It seems like no matter what I do, the authentication is getting saved somewhere. The domain its authenticating against doesn't seem to be saved in the `sharedCredentialStorage`.

When I set `canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace` as false, it doesn't use `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge`, but the auth credentials (which are a part of the url rather than the challenge response) still seemed to get cached!

This seemingly straight forward problem isn't turning out to be straight forward and is extremely frustrating. May all of this be a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credentials are often stored as cookies; try deleting all stored cookies.